# Pin should be lock for sample A warning in Pic

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, microchip

In an ADC i'm trying to configure for a pic `PIC 32MX470F512LT` its giving me a warning, that like the title says, it's that the pin should be locked for sample A.

I don't know what it's the sample A in the warning.

What is the cause of that?

[image: o]

Comment: please clraify the question. What is a sample A?

Comment: @Mike hi, i don't know what is sample A. That's why i don't understand the warning.